# Icon trigger datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using jqueryui datepicker to replace my existing popup date picker.

I copy 100% from this sample http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger

The problem is the icon is not centered with the datefield. I try change something in the css file but fail.

Comment: When you say the icon is not center with the datefield, do you mean vertically? Can you take a small screen capture to show what you mean?

Comment: As you can see from the sample, icon trigger were align with top of the datefield

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will depend on your exact CSS (you haven't given us anything to go off), but if you put `vertical-align: middle;` on both the icon and the `<input>` then you will achieve vertical centering.

Comment: You're right, i put hasDatepicker class with vertical-align: middle and now it working great